# Segmenting video by GStreamer

Tags: linux, video, gstreamer

```
gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src ! videorate ! x264enc ! avimux ! filesink location=result.avi
```

After executing command have the video "result.avi".

I need: "2012-04-22_15-30-00.avi", "2012-04-22_15-31-00.avi" etc. How do I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can

1. pause recording, rename the recorded file, restart (will loose a handful of frames)
2. use multifilesink (no frame loss, but a simple naming pattern like file_0001.avi, file_0002.avi and you need signalling to switch to a new file (e.g. an eos timer)).

There are more way, but it quickly gets more complicated.

Comment: Thanks, but these methods do not fit me. Please, tell me about another method.

Comment: Maybe you expand your initial question and describe your constrains.